# How to use unzOpenCurrentFilePassword?

Tags: unzip

Can someone help me port my code from
`void * uzFile = unzOpen("zip filename");`

to use the unzOpenCurrentFilePassword from minizip ? 
I want to protect my zip file with a password.

I tried many times but I failed using it. Thanks

`extern int ZEXPORT unzOpenCurrentFilePassword OF((unzFile file,
                                                  const char* password));
/*
  Open for reading data the current file in the zipfile.
  password is a crypting password
  If there is no error, the return value is UNZ_OK.
*/`

Answer (score 11):

Before you compile zlib, remove the definition of NOUNCRYPT in unzip.c. Then "unzOpenCurrentFilePassword will be enabled".

unzip.c Line 72:

```
#ifndef NOUNCRYPT
    //#define NOUNCRYPT Comment this line, so unzip protected files will be enabled
#endif
```

Why? Among other things, the definition of NOUNCRYPT causes an absurd return in unzOpenCurrentFilePassword function.

```
extern int ZEXPORT unzOpenCurrentFile3 (unzFile file, int* method,
                                        int* level, int raw, const char* password)
[...]

#   ifndef NOUNCRYPT
    char source[12];
#   else
    if (password != NULL)
        return UNZ_PARAMERROR;
#   endif
```